# Is there any tool to simulate an app store upload and show errors?

Tags: ios, app-store

I'm working on an app on iOS, but I'm not the one who publish it on the app store. So each time I have to send the build to the third party who try to upload it and come back to me with upload errors. This way, we are both wasting time and the release is delayed.

Is there any tool that would allow me to see if there is any "TRC" error on the build before sending to the third party?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use the "Validate..." feature in the Xcode Organizer (Window -> Organizer) to identify any issues with your binary ahead of you sending it to the third party.

[image]

Note: This will require some level of access to the third party's iTunes Connect account.  Additionally, it will require that the application is actually created in iTunes Connect with a matching bundle identifier.

I'm guessing, without actually trying it, that this permission will align with "Upload Builds" in this screenshot, so you would need Developer, App Manager, Admin, or Legal:

[image]

Comment: ok then it's the access I am missing, because I tried that and I cannot choose the "Use local signing" when I try to validate, I have to sign with my own account, and that's bad because it does not match the signing identity I used when compiling. Do you know what level of access I need, so I can ask for it please?

Comment: I updated my answer with a screenshot and suggestion

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to "preflight" the entire submission procedure:

In your own personal Developer account on iTunes Connect, create a dummy app with a dummy bundle ID.  Temporarily change the bundle ID and owner of your client's app to this dummy ID, build, and upload to your own Developer account (not the client's).  After the Validation and upload succeeds 100%, delete this build from your iTC app version (so you can re-use the dummy bundle ID as many times as needed).  Throw away the dummy app archive, and send the identical (except for bundle ID) app to your client.

You can even copy all the client's My App : App Information and Version Details to your dummy app entry to see if that causes any problems when hitting "Save" in iTunes Connect.  Even if you hit "Submit" by accident, you can always reject this submitted build to reuse your dummy app ID.

Comment: It's not a bad idea either but it multiplies the manipulations and therefore is prone to more errors. But I'll keep that in mind if some clients don't want to add me as a dev on their app. thanks for your contribution